# How to Drag and Drop files to open application?

Tags: files, ubuntu-dock, drag-and-drop

Since Ubuntu 18.04 I can't drag a file e.g. image file to an open application such as Inkscape or [Evolution](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution) email message window.

In Ubuntu 17.10 I was able to select the image file by clicking on it, and while holding down left mouse button I would hit the supper key displaying all open windows where for there I could then drop the file in any open app or folders. This is no longer possible/default behaviour since Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to achieve this or even a way to recreate the same behaviour like in 17.10?

Comment: You can DnD on open windows. You can't DnD on icons in the launcher or in the activities overview. Note that the snap version of inkscape can't open files on other volumes in any fashion.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/fix-drag-drop-ubuntu/ hop its help you and other

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Encouraging update** (Nov 2020) after waiting since **[**2012**](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issue-9576295)** (!), see also [github-comment from 2015](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issuecomment-93854316):
[vadikom](https://github.com/vadikom) presented [an approach](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issuecomment-720976751) to get it working with the [GNOME extension Dash-to-Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and Pop!_OS). **Please test it and comment!**

If you would like to **test** it:

1. Find and backup the following file: `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/dash.js`
2. Make a copy of the file `dash.js`
3. Open the file `dash.js` with a text editor and replace the content with the text from the [Github User Content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadikom/dash-to-dock/master/dash.js).
4. Hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reload GNOME shell.

For some **known issues** and thoughts see [vadikom's post](http://Known%20issues).
Source code on the [fork of Dash-to-Dock](https://github.com/vadikom/dash-to-dock).
A [short **video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNKTbDRbt1I) about how it looks like.

Apart from that there are two ways of **one inconvenient possibility** (see comment below):

- **Left-click** on the file, **hold** it, press the keys **<kbd>alt</kbd> and press as many times the key <kbd>tab</kbd>** to navigate to the window you want to drag the file to (while still holding the left-click), release <kbd>alt</kbd> when the right application window is chosen and drag the file to the desired place to drop. (This is difficult on a laptop while using the touch pad, though, easier with a mouse.)
- If you click on <kbd>alt</kbd> & <kbd>tab</kbd> and **hold <kbd>alt</kbd>** (as well as the left-click on the file, the **overview of all opened windows/apps** will open and you can move the cursor over the appropriate window and finally release the file there when the windows is opened ([Thanks fcole90](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issuecomment-495537956)).
  With **Nautilus**, it looks like this only works if the files are in **list view** not icon view!

[For some it works **without the keyboard**](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issuecomment-495597927), but just the mouse or touchpad or whatever you use to move your cursor. You **drag the element to the bar**, this triggers the overview window, you then drag the item to the window you want, then the window get focus, finally release your item.

[Kyriakos Loizou](https://askubuntu.com/users/824513/kyriakos-loizou) suggests the [same behaviour but with left-click on the file [I have to **drag** the file to the Dash to Dock] and then click & hold the <kbd>super</kbd> (while still holding the left-click)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037424/30631). This triggers the overview window, you then drag the item to the window you want, then the window get focus, finally release your item.

There is also a [bugzilla-report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696321). Maybe we can all **subscribe to this [bugzilla-thread](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696321) and the [github-thread](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49#issuecomment-93854316)** to show the support for it and please contribute or comment** with your reaction (smiley, thumb up, ...). I think this feature is crucial for Ubuntu and without it a real pain.

Comment: Very true, it's a pain not having this feature. I've been with Ubuntu since version 7.04 and was actually excited to see it move back to Gnome. But I must say honestly, it feels like some issues haven't been thought through very well.  In regards to dragging and dropping, you can actually drag the file to an open application or folder using alt+tap, but doing this on a laptop while using the mouse pad to drag the file at the same time is very awkward.

Comment: Would this work with the "built-in" dock extension in Ubuntu 22.04? For example, would it be safe and sound to try and replace the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/dash.js` with this mod?

Comment: Also, would this work on Ubuntu with Dolphin as the default file manager?

Answer (score 6):

What you might be trying is to drag the file to the application shortcut. This feature is not available in Ubuntu 18.04 as far as I know.

A simple and better trick:

- **Step#1:** Click and drag the file just to hold it.
- **Step#2:** Press Alt+Tab on your keyboard and keep pressing the Tab until you reach the desired window where you want to drop.
- **Step#3:** When you see your the window where you want to drop, just release the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following command in your terminal. It worked for me on ubuntu 18.04.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on ubuntu 20 unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As of today, I have noticed that you can now select a file with Left-click and while holding the mouse button down you can then press the <kbd>super</kbd> button on the keyboard. This will preview all running applications or open folder. Then, while you're still holding the mouse button down, move the mouse over the application/folder you would like to move/add it to, hover over it for 2-3 seconds and it will become focused, now you can drop the file there and it should be added.

I have tested this behaviour with an image file dropping it into Inkscape and works like a charm. I'm not sure how effective this is with other applications, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.